# how to send json object to server using volley in android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

> I want to send the JSONObject to server using POST method . I have used volley library to pass the string params its working fine, but if i try to use json object its showing an error for calling the json object here is my code

```
    private void makeJsonObjReq() {
    showProgressDialog();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            Const.URL_LOGIN, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("un", "xyz@gmail.com");
            params.put("p", "somepasswordhere");
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,tag_json_obj);

    // Cancelling request
    // ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag_json_obj);       
}
```

> And my Error form server is : `[10031] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401`

How to solve this problem. I want to add `application/json;charset=utf-8`  in header please check my code whether its correct or not . Please give me a suggestion to over come this problem

Comment: third parameter in `JsonObjectRequest` is for passing post parameters in jsonobject form. And for header you need to send two separate values one for content-type one for charset.

Comment: @Pr38y :  getParams() will be the Third parameter in JsonObjectRequest right??? and headers.put("Content-Type", "charset=utf-8"); is this right??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Third parameter in JsonObjectRequest is for passing post parameters in jsonobject form. And for header you need to send two separate values one for content-type one for charset.

```
  RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

  private void makeJsonObjReq() {
    showProgressDialog();


            Map<String, String> postParam= new HashMap<String, String>();
            postParam.put("un", "xyz@gmail.com");
            postParam.put("p", "somepasswordhere");


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            Const.URL_LOGIN, new JSONObject(postParam),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }



    };

    jsonObjReq.setTag(TAG);
    // Adding request to request queue
    queue.add(jsonObjReq);

    // Cancelling request
    /* if (queue!= null) {
    queue.cancelAll(TAG);
    } */

}
```

Comment: What is JsonObject class?

Comment: @John could you please send me your whole class of this volley [java file] to my email id : arsalanali13@gmail.com , i will be very grateful to u

Comment: am facing the same problem thats why am asking you your complete java file..THnks in advance

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan were you are facing the problem , i have updated my code long back. explain me the problem so that i can help you

Comment: @John please check my similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067507/how-to-send-sqlite-data-from-android-to-mysql-server?noredirect=1#comment57859091_35067507

Comment: in addition to this answer if you use asp web api as your api service make sure that your method argument include in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Create new Method and call it in OnClick method

```
public void PostOperation() {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pdialog.setMessage("Loading");
        pdialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "YOUR_URL",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                        Log.e("login output", response);
//MODEL CLASS
                       LoginModel loginModel = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response, LoginModel.class);


                        if (loginModel.getStatus().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {


                            Intent i = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();

                            Toast.makeText(context, loginModel.getStatus() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(context, loginModel.getMsg() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

              // pass your input text

                map.put("email" editTextEmail.getText().toString()); 
                map.put("password",editTextPassword.getText().toString() );

                map.put("uid", "1"); 
                map.put("type", "login");


                Log.e("para", map + "");
                return map;
            }

        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```