# How to post following JSON api using volley in android?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

```
{

  "CustomerSK": 1,

  "CareTakerName": "sample string 2",

  "Relationship": "sample string 3",

  "MobileNo": "sample string 4",

  "MailID": "sample string 5",

  "VitallimitList": [

    {

      "VitalType": "sample string 1",

      "VitalMinValue": "sample string 2",

      "VitalMaxValue": "sample string 3"

    },

    {

      "VitalType": "sample string 1",

      "VitalMinValue": "sample string 2",

      "VitalMaxValue": "sample string 3"

    }

  ],

  "NotificationType": [

    "sample string 1",

    "sample string 2"

  ]

}
```

Comment: use jsonobject request , google it , try reading the link in below comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send json object to server using volley in andorid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344448/how-to-send-json-object-to-server-using-volley-in-andorid)